# Advice to make php ID specific rather than recent post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been working with the php file (on a wordpress custom theme which won't be updated at any point) to make the home page.php pull in three posts. It was initially set up by another developer who had it working with another dbase so I am trying to make the posts I have inserted fit with the existing php. Could anyone help me out by suggesting what I can put to change the code to fit specific post ID rather than recnet posts? Or if you know of any tutorials which would help me as I cannot find anything.

**Code**

```
     <?php
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'desc',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    // 'post_parent' => '90',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args, $output = ARRAY_A);
foreach ($recent_posts as $recent) {
?>

                        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                            <a href="<?php
    echo get_permalink($recent['ID']);
?><?php
    echo get_permalink($post->ID);
?>" title="<?php
    echo esc_attr($recent['post_title']);
?>" >

                                <div class="feature-item">

                                    <?php
    if (has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"])) {
?>
                                       <?php
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($recent["ID"]), 'single-post-thumbnail');
?>                    
                                        <img src='<?php
        echo $image[0];
?>' style='width: 100%; border-radius: 6px'>
                                    <?php
    }
?>

                                    <div class='feature-title'><?php
    echo $recent['post_title'];
?></div>
                                    <div class='feature-content'><?php
    echo substr($recent['post_content'], 0, 80);
?></div>              
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <?php
}
?>
```

I have tried simply changing the args to have:

```
$args = array(
                    'numberposts' => 1, 
                    'post_type' => 'page',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'ID' => '268');
```

but realise the  $recent_posts commands throw out the ID function.

Any help massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/):

```
$post_268 = get_post(268);
// Do something with the $post_268. Example:
echo $post_268->post_title;
```

Of course, you're also going to need to change the rest of the code to account for this new variable.